# How to change a navbar UIBarButtonItem button to a navbar back button?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIViewController` with a navigation bar i dropped in in storyboards.  Then I dragged in a `UIBarButtonItem` which is rectangular.

[image: NavBar with UIBarButtonItem]

I want that button to look like a navigation bar's back button

[image: Nav Bar Back Button]

I was suggested to do this:

```
self.navBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem = self.button;
```

After properly creating the properties and connecting them to the outlet.  I did but the button still looks like the Done Rectangular button.  How can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those buttons are created automatically when you do a push segue.
For your particular problem, you can call perform `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` in the case of modal segues, or `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` for dismissing custom push segues.

Anyway, I don't know any method to change the button style to the "left arrow", other than selecting a background image with your particular "button".

[image: UIBarButtonItem Image]

Comment: But one can only add a background image to a UIButton.  And UIButtons cannot be added to navigation bars.  Whenever I drag a rectangular button to the navbar it just turns it back into a UIBarButtonItem.  So does that mean its not possible?

Comment: Are you sure? If I click a UIBarButtonItem (the "Salir" button), there is an "image" field in the Attributes Inspector :/ look at the image I added...

Comment: Yeah but it's not a background image.  It's an image inside the button.  Add an image and you'll see.  I added the left-tipped image I posted in the original question and its simply placed over the rectangular button image in the back.